# Asp.net life cycle event to change Response.Cookies

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, webforms

In Asp.Net, is there any life cycle event from where I can modify the  Response Cookies ?
I want a common place where I can set the SameSite flag on all cookies added by any code. I also need an access to HttpContext.Current.Session in that event.
I already tried PreSendRequestHeaders, PostReleaseRequestState, PostAcquireRequestState and EndRequest but none of them worked.

Comment: The right answer is [PreSendRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.8). What do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: @JohnWu Session is null in PreSendRequestHeaders event.

Comment: Cant you do it in the web.config? Something like ````<httpCookies sameSite="Lax" httpOnlyCookies="true" />```` and ````<sessionState cookieSameSite="Lax" />```` ?

Comment: @JohnPete22 No, because I want clients to control that and it may be different for different clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be achieved in one event. 
So I used PreSendRequestHeaders to change the response.cookies.
It doesn't have access to Session object, but I added required session variables in Request.Cookies in Session_Start event. 
Note: Adding something in Request.Cookies doesn't make any change in response cookies.